LaravelでLarabergを安全に使いたい
Laravelを最近使い始めたのですが、HTML、CSSの知識がない方でも管理できるブログサイトを作成したく、LaravelでGutenbergが使える Laraberg というものを見つけたので実装しました。
しかしscriptタグを入力するとそのまま反映されてしまい、サニタイズがされていない状態です。
そのため Purifier というものを使って有害なタグは入れられないようにしようと思ったのですが、エディタにテキストのみ入力してページを更新すると、以下のエラーがでてしまいます。
Element 'iframe' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)

開発ツールのNetworkのPayloadで送信された内容を確認しましたが、以下のようになっており、iframeは含まれていません。
<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>てすと</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->

そもそも、ブロックエディタに対し、Purifierで許可するタグを設定していくのも冗長な気もしています。
Larabergのようなエディタを導入する場合にサニタイズをするのに適したものなどがあれば
是非ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
